# How i can make a android webview app open directly in browser

Tags: android, browser, webview

I want to make a webview app and when opened start in the browser directly, or show the pop out to choose the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will open the the chrome browser with the link you specify.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("http://putawebsitehere.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will open link on WebBrowser or it will show choose dialog if You have more than one application that can handle this type of Action.

```
Uri urlUri= Uri.parse("http://www.link.com/"); 
Intent showBrowser= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, urlUri);  
startActivity(showBrowser);
```